# Implementing search in listview

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a PDF reader. I've created a list view which will hold all the PDF files you're having in your mobile.

Now when I'm implementing a search on this listview using EditText field, the problem is, it is not able to search files properly, like for example, I've 5 files named as
sample.pdf, resume-sample.pdf, resume sample.pdf, resume.pdf, sampleresume.pdf.

Now if I search:

1. "sample" I'll get the following result: sample.pdf and resume sample.pdf
2. "resume" I'll get the following result: resume sample.pdf and resume.pdf

As we can see this is not the exact result of what we expect, it should have listed all the files having either "sample" or "resume" in it.

It is able to search only when the 2 words are separated having space between them, it is not able to read the second word if there is no space or _ or - between the 2 words.

Please let me know if it is possible to implement a perfect search for my problem, thank you.

This is the code for my EditText listener:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence a, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence a, int start, int before, int count) {
            pdf.arradapter.getFilter().filter(a.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable a) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well if you manage the collection of PDF document names yourself, you may implement any search logic which you wish, including a custom regular expression.  Maybe add more code which shows how to control the list of files which are open/in scope.

Comment: If `arradapter` is a regular `ArrayAdapter`, its `Filter` only does two checks on the given `String`: the first is `startsWith()` on the whole `String`; the second splits the `String` on a space, and then checks `startsWith()` on each "word". If you want `contains()` instead, you'll have to write your own `Filter`, or possibly find an existing implementation somewhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the list is sorted in case-insensitive order using custom-made "searchpdf" function which searches for available pdf files in the external storage, then it stores the result in an array adapter which is displayed using the list view.

Comment: @Titanknight_71 Read Mike M's comment, because it sounds like what I imagine you would have to do here.  You need to implement your own search behavior, because the default isn't specific enough to be useful for your app.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I make my custom function to implement the kind of search I need, how can I use it within the EditText Listener?

Comment: @MikeM. If I make my custom function to implement the kind of search I need, how can I use it within the EditText Listener?

Comment: The same way you're using `ArrayAdapter`'s now. The implementation would be in the `Adapter`. The external usage wouldn't change. Really, it should only take a minute or two to copy and modify `ArrayAdapter`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java.

Comment: @MikeM. but this customsearchfunction should be only implemented when the user is searching something in the EditText field, so I think it should be implemented in the listener of EditText, no?

Comment: No. I'm not sure why you would think that. Look at how you're doing it now. You get the `Filter` from the `Adapter`, and call `filter()` on it. That wouldn't change. You're just modifying the `Filter` class.

Comment: @MikeM. this getfilter or the filter function is inbuilt function of this listener, which you get as soon as you make this listener. But, I don't know if the same thing is possible with customsearchfunction or not?, will check it and let you know, thanks for your help.

Comment: No, `getFilter()` is a method in `ArrayAdapter`; `filter()` is in `Filter`. They are not directly related to your `TextWatcher` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search View instead. Just create a menu.xml file which contain this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_icon"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

inflate the menu inside your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() to your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id. search_icon:
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
                searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                searchView.setQueryHint("PLACEHOLDER");
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

you can manipulate your list inside onQueryTextChange(String newText) method

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
       newText = newText.toLowerCase();
       List<Item> newTransaction = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Item item : getData()) {
            String name = item.getItem_name().toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(newText))
                newTransaction.add(item);
            }
            adapter.setFilters(newTransaction);
            return true;
      }
}
```

Adapter is your custom adapter for your Adapter List View, getData return list, and inside the setFilters method

```
public void setFilters(List<Item> filters) {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.addAll(filters);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I hope that helps. You can check this tutorial if you are confused [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoEY2n8CCSk)

Comment: All of this runs on the main thread, which is not a good idea.

Comment: what makes it so bad? @MikeM.

Comment: The main thread is the UI thread, so it can cause lag and stutters.